# pageBlockSection under pageBlockSection

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to have `pageBlockSection` under `pageBlockSection` but as shown in the picture the sub-section of pageBlockSection is all the way to right side, how can I have pageBlockSection under pageBlockSection?

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:actionRegion >
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Employee" id="pbs0" columns="2"   >            
   <apex:inputField value="{!employee__c.Is_active__c}"> 
     <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="pbs1,pbs2" />
   </apex:inputField>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>  
</apex:actionRegion>

<apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs1" columns="2" >
  <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.Start_Date__c}" />
  <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.End_Date__c}" />
  ........
 <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs2" columns="2" title="Related List"> 

  </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the nested page block section is off to the right is that it's parent page block section has two columns, and the nested section is being crammed into the right column.

If you make the parent section have just one column, your nested section will be more spread out.

As for the fields above it, you could also put them in a nested page block section, and make the nested section have two columns.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >

<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1"  >

<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="false" >
    <apex:inputText value="{!Account.name}"  />
    <apex:inputText value="{!Account.name}" />
    <apex:inputText value="{!Account.name}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" title="SecondSection"  >
    <apex:inputText value="{!Account.name}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlockSection>


</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I want the parent pageblocksection to have `two columns` and i see that if  parent section have 1 column then the nested pageblocksection rendered correctly. is that the only way to have one column in parent pageblocsection?

Comment: @NickKahn That's how I would go about it anyways; just create a nested pageBlockSection for each part that you want to have two columns.

Comment: so you saying I can not have parent pageblockSection with two columns and nested with two columns?

Comment: @NickKahn Yes, I believe that is the case.